# Why is WUBI limited to 30GB?

Tags: windows, wubi

Why is the maximum size of a WUBI-Installation limited to 30GB? If someone has 1TB hdd drive but can't format or create new partitions it would be great to have a bigger wubi.

Comment: If someone has a 1TB drive, that guy should install it directly on it using a CD / USB without using Wubi.

Answer (score 2):

It is a design decision: Wubi is intented to be used for first time users of Ubuntu and should help answering questions like "Is Ubuntu something I can use?" without having to do any formatting, creating partitions or any other instruction that could potentially destroy their previously used OS.

If you want a full fledged install with lots of free space and any feature you might desire you will have to install it with as a multi-boot (or as a single OS removing any other OS).

Answer (score 1):

I would like not to be forced to use Wubi, but my Dell XPS 630i with a hardware RAID 1 does not allow me to use anything else.  I have tried many times to have an Ubuntu - Windows Vista dual boot, but the only Linux CD/DVD that I can boot from is OpenSuse (and it's not a Live one).
I really wish to overcome such constraint, but I could only switch to a Wubi solution :-(

Comment: Hey how i can know how much space I did allocated to the Ubuntu Installation ?